# Raleigh M20 with broken rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur-rear

Broken rear derailleur.

What do I need to look for to replace a RD-TX30?

Comment: We don't do product recommendations.

Comment: Looking online, it seems the Raleigh M20 has 21 gears, so has a 7 speed cassette. So you'd be looking at a Shimano 7 speed compatible rear derailleur to replace the existing one to avoid the possibility of replacing other parts too. I presume the RD-TX30 is a "piece of junk" because it's broken? I've only ever replaced rear derailleurs when they've broken or I've upgraded to extra gears - once setup correctly, they all pretty much work the same...

Answer (score 1):

You can use most common Shimano rear mountain derailers made for 9 speed cassettes or fewer.

Currently, good value choices would be the mid-range Deore RD-M591 for a bike that sees a lot of use that you want to keep going, or Altus RD-M310 if you want the cheapest reasonable option. Both meet or surpass the total capacity, min/max sprocket size, and max chainring difference numbers of RD-TX30, so they'll both be compatible anywhere TX30 was.

Comment: At RRP, putting Deore on a bike that retailed at $200 10 years ago is throwing good money after bad. However, on discount at popular online stores they are similar, if not cheaper, than lower quality models, so its worth shopping around.